# Debounce in Redux Saga

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga, debouncing

I found this useful little function to throttle based on which key is saving in Redux Saga

```
export default function* throttlePerKey(pattern:string, selector: Function, timeout:number, saga:any) {
    const set = new Set()
  
    while(true) {
      const action = yield take(pattern)
      const id = selector(action)
      const throttled = set.has(id)
     
      if (throttled) {
         
      } else {
        set.add(id)
        // Expire items after timeout
        yield fork(function* () {
          yield delay(timeout)
          set.delete(id)
        })
        yield call(saga, action)
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm trying now to make it debounce instead. So you always get the last one.

Any clues how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the action happens for the first time, you can fork a task that sets a delay followed by a call to the saga, and save the task object. If the action happens a second time soon after, you'll cancel the task and start another one. Once enough time passes without any actions, the last task will make it past its delay, and call the saga.

```
export default function* debouncePerKey(pattern:string, selector: Function, timeout:number, saga:any) {
  const map = new Map()

  while(true) {
    const action = yield take(pattern)
    const id = selector(action)
    const existingTask = map.get(id)

    if (existingTask) {
      yield cancel(existingTask)
    }
   
    const newTask = yield fork(function* () {
      yield delay(timeout)
      map.delete(id)
      yield call(saga, action)
    })

    map.set(id, newTask)
  }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking something similar. Any reason to use a Map rather than a plain old object?

Comment: I would have used an object myself. I only used a Map to keep it more similar to your example, which used a Set.